# Cross-reference to theorems from other files

Tags: xr, xr-hyper

Really simple example. Say I have two files:

```
# first.tex:
\documentclass[acmtog,anonymous,review]{acmart}

\begin{document}

\section{}\label{sec:first}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:first}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

and

```
# second.tex:
\documentclass[acmtog,anonymous,review]{acmart}
\usepackage{xr}

\externaldocument{first}

\begin{document}

\section{Proofs of \autoref{sec:first}}

\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

I think what I would like to achieve is obvious: I want to have a section in second.tex which has the heading "Proof of section 1". For some reason, that doesn't work. I get the warning: *Package xr Warning:  No file first.aux LABELS NOT IMPORTED. on input line 4*. But why?

I also would like to have a theorem-like environment in second.tex of the kind "Proof of \autoref{thm:first}". How can I get that?

Comment: well do you have a `first.aux` file (from running latex on `first.tex`) ?

Comment: @DavidCarlisle Ah, I see. How do I get that? I'm compiling these things on overleaf. It seems like overleaf always calls the output `output`. Can I change that somehow?

Comment: see https://www.overleaf.com/learn/how-to/Cross_referencing_with_the_xr_package_in_Overleaf

Answer (score 1):

There are a number of issues you have to take care of for this to work.

The first thing, given the error you report ("Package xr Warning: No file first.aux LABELS NOT IMPORTED."), says @DavidCarlisle is right (as usual), and you are missing your `first.aux` file. So you have to run latex on `first.tex` as a first step, and that will create the `first.aux` file with the labels to be imported.

With that in hand, if you run latex on `second.tex` the labels will be imported, but than you'll get a number of "multiply defined" labels, because `acmart` sets a number of internal labels (for ToC, total pages, etc.) and these will be necessarily identical between the two documents, thus the clash. So you can use a prefix to import the labels from `first.aux` (the optional argument to `\externaldocument`):

```tex
\externaldocument[F-]{first}
```

(`F-` for "first", but whatever prefix you prefer).

Than you can refer in `second.tex` to labels imported from `first` adding the prefix to the labels, for example, `F-sec:first`.

Furthermore, `acmart` uppercases section titles, so if you use `\section{Proofs of \autoref{F-sec:first}}`, you'll get the warning "Reference 'F-SEC:FIRST' on page 1 undefined". What's going on is that the label itself is being uppercased alongside with the title, so the label is not found.  `acmart` uses `textcase` for the job, which offers `\NoCaseChange` to protect pieces of material in such circumstances. But `\autoref` complicates things a little, because if you wrap it in `\NoCaseChange` the reference name will remain lowercased. I think the simplest here is to just use a standard reference:

```tex
\section{Proofs of section~\NoCaseChange{\ref{F-sec:first}}}
```

Also, the use of `\NoCaseChange` will make `hyperref` complain about "Token not allowed in a PDF string". You can take care of that by locally disabling `\NoCaseChange` for producing bookmarks with:

```tex
\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \renewcommand{\NoCaseChange}[1]{#1}%
}
```

Finally, since `acmart` loads `hyperref`, to get correct hyperlinks to the other document, you should load `xr-hyper` instead (a bird tells me this might no longer be needed in the future, but currently it still is).

Putting things together. `first.tex`:

```tex
\documentclass[acmtog,anonymous,review]{acmart}

\begin{document}

\section{}\label{sec:first}

\begin{theorem}\label{thm:first}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

`second.tex`:

```tex
\documentclass[acmtog,anonymous,review]{acmart}
\usepackage{xr-hyper}

\externaldocument[F-]{first}

\pdfstringdefDisableCommands{%
  \renewcommand{\NoCaseChange}[1]{#1}%
}

\begin{document}

\section{Proofs of section~\NoCaseChange{\ref{F-sec:first}}}

\begin{theorem}
\end{theorem}

\end{document}
```

Will result in:

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! That can I do with the theorem proof? In `second.tex` I want that instead of "Theorem 1.1" the environment text is "Proof of Theorem \ref{thm:first}". How do I get that?

Comment: @0xbadf00d Just do that, it is a standard label. But remember, imported labels with the prefix, so `\ref{F-thm:first}`.